# Lock other users from using my workstation

Tags: windows-7

I don't like other people using my workstation in my absence How do I lock a workstation that is configured to let anyone with valid credentials to log in as a different user?

Comment: Is this computer joined to a Windows Domain?  Are you the Domain Administrator?  Do you have local Administrator privileges?  A Domain Admin will be able to undo anything you set as a local admin as long as your machine is on the Domain.  If you aren't a local admin, then you can't really do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how your work environment is currently configured, but local group policy can be used IF you have admin privileges (refer to  Zoredache's comment above).

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor.
2. In the left pane, click on to expand Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, and Logon. (See screenshot below)

[image]

3. In the right pane, right click on Hide entry points for Fast User Switching and click on Edit. (See screenshot above)
4. To Add Switch User to CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen
   A) Select (dot) either Not Configured or Disabled. (See screenshot below step 6)

B) Go to step 6.

5. To Remove Switch User from CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen
   A) Select (dot) Enabled. (See screenshot below step 6)
6. Click on OK. (See screenshot below)
   [image]
7. Close the Local Group Policy Editor window.
8. Restart the computer to fully apply.

See the following links:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-switch-user-option-in-windows-vista-and-7/

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63025-ctrl-alt-del-start-menu-add-remove-switch-user.html

Comment: How does disabling fast user switching do anything useful?  Removing fast user switching doesn't prevent me from going up to a machine, physically restarting it and logging in if I have a valid account on the system/domain.

Comment: I absolutely agree.  Just attempting to answer his incredibly vague question.